# Term for distinctive wasp flight pattern

Tags: phrases, idioms, expressions, terminology

Many wasps have a characteristic way of flying back and forth while approaching the opening to their nest (see for example the intro paragraph in [this Wikipedia article on yellow jackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_jacket)).

Is there a term for this characteristic flight behaviour? In entomology, in folklore? I have searched, but found nothing.

Comment: Huh, interesting. If you don't get an answer here after a while, come on over to [Biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com). We have a few entomologists who hang out there and they should know.

Comment: Great suggestion @terdon. I did not know there is a Biology.SE.

Comment: Yeah, we're still in beta. Just make sure to remove any references to folklore and stick to asking for an 'official scientific' term :).

Comment: terdon just wants you to ask over there so he can close the same question down on two sites

Comment: The opening paragraph in the Wiki states the wasps can be identified by a characteristic "*rapid, side to side* flight pattern prior to landing." Google returns about 9,300,000 results for *zig-zag flight + wasp.*

Comment: Thank you @RaghuramMK however I'm not sure how that answers my question.

Comment: @JAM: I misparsed. One source I found just says they *hover.* I remember reading somewhere that bees do that to ascertain if there's danger lurking inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are commonly referred as " *Orientation flights* " 
 You can read more about this [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00189396)